# PythonAnywere to connect postgres

Tags: python, django

**how to use postgres remotely in my pythonanywhere
I need to make this kind of connection to postgres database in Anywhere but it is not supported
**

'''

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'fontenariaguivala',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '**********',
        'HOST': 'mayhoste.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

'''

Comment: makes all connections and agrees to migrate but the site does not run when connected with postgres remotely

Comment: Do you have open an redirected port?

Comment: it seems that to use postgres database by default there is some procedure to follow and I don't know what it is
What I did works great and accepts to migrate the problem is when I make this connection my website stops working because pythonanywhere does not accept accessing postgres remotely from outside

Comment: you have to use and configure NAT on router

Comment: Are you using a free account on PythonAnywhere?  Free accounts can only make outbound HTTP and HTTPS requests, and for those they can only access sites on an [allowlist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/).  So you would not be able to connect to a remote Postgres server from a free account.

Comment: My account is paid

Comment: my account was paid

Comment: the connection works very well and accepts to migrate the problem is that when I make the connection my site stops working but when I reconnect the sqlite the site works again.

wouldn't it be the python version and some errors?
but where do these errors come from

Comment: @BaptistaGuivala can you post the errors that you are seeing?